# Why Homebrew didn't removed Python directory?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I ran `brew uninstall python` but there's still the directory `/usr/local/lib/python2.7`.

Why brew didn't removed it? Is it still used? Can I remove it manually?

Comment: My guess is that you had own files in that directory, if that is the case it should be fine to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` is a directory shared with the system and it isn't owned by Homebrew: as you might now `usr/local/Cellar` is the proper Homebrew folder (along with several other spurious folders for taps and Cask).
It mainly contains packages (installed using `pip`).
I wouldn't touch such folder, since it is shared with the Python installation provided by OS X (through XCode Command Line Tools): if for any reasons (but I don't think so since you uninstalled python through Homebrew) you still have `pip` installed I would recommend to uninstall such packages through `pip` itself if you want to cleanup some space.